# How to send zip file on server using background Service in Android

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

In my app user fills some fields and i save user data in a file
Now i want to send all files to server when internet is available.
In which way i can implement a service 
which use less resource Like Battery. 
Check connectivity after certain intervals? if yes then make zip of all files and send to server using Restful Post method in one connection call (I am confuse about that)
Any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Two Options, Two Ways:

First Option: If you are storing data from user input, you can use SQLite to store those inputs in database tables and then use the Restful Post to post the stored data to a web service.

Second Option: if you are storing files (photos, attachments, media) from user inputs, then you can upload those files to a server using ftp protocol, it is better than to post your files and gives you more security options on what files can be uploaded to your server

Good luck